# Number of x-values is cropped

Tags: javascript, highcharts

### Explanation:

I've been using [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts) for 5 days and  I have a problem:

I have a series with about 250 x-values, but when the area chart is drawn only 65 values are shown.

### Question:

How can I get the chart going with 250 values?

Comment: Please add  what you've tried to your question.

Comment: Could you prepare an online demo with your issue (jsfiddle, codepen)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HighCharts-Code:

```
                        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('elevations', {
                        chart: {type: 'area', backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 1000},
                        title: { text: '' },
                        tooltip: {
                            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                            borderColor: '#5e88ff', borderWidth: 2,
                            useHTML: true,
                            headerFormat: '<table><tr><td>bei Kilometer:</td><td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.key}</b></td></tr>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            valueDecimals: 1
                        },
                        xAxis: { categories: distNew },
                        yAxis: { title: { text: 'Meter' }, lineColor: '#5e88ff', lineWidth: 2 },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Höhenmeter',
                            data: elevations,
                            showInLegend: false,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            color: '#000000',
                            animation: { duration: 5000 },
                            zones: [{
                                value: 250,
                                fillColor: '#cad8ff',
                            }, {
                                value: 500,
                                fillColor: '#b4c8ff'
                            }, {
                                value: 750,
                                fillColor: '#98b3ff'
                            }, {
                                fillColor: '#5e88ff'
                                }]
                        }]
                    });
```

distNew (array) has **250** values, but shown in the chart are only **65**.